# Why is the slew rate in nMOS amplifiers worst when the output is going from low to high?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, mosfet, slew-rate

Likewise, why is the slew rate in pMOS amplifiers worst in the other case? (Output going from high to low.)

Comment: Are you talking about a single NMOS or PMOS transistor operated open-drain with pull-up/down resistor? Or an amplifier with complementary N and P MOS transistors? Or an amplifier with either two N or two P transistors "totem pole" style?

Comment: I'm thinking about a Source Follower amplifier like this: http://elettronica-plus.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/05/figura2.jpg (there should also be a Load Cap on the output)

Comment: That's a common-source amplifier, not a follower.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on the scheme you are employing to drive the gate of the output transistor.

Firstly, understand that the gate of a MOSFET is just a capacitor that must be charged and discharged to control the transistor's state.

Then, if you imagine that the system in control of the transistor's gate is composed of more transistors, each of which is really just a switch, off or on, we can model all the possible configurations.

Below, C represents the gate of the output transistor \$M_{OUT}\$, and SW1 and SW2 represent transistors M1 and M2 tasked with charging and discharging C:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQH9K1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$M_{OUT}\$ is only able to switch on or off as quickly as the voltage at its gate can rise or fall. Considering its gate is a capacitor needing to be  charged or discharged, the rate of charging and discharging is obviously key.

On the left above, C can by very quickly discharged by closing SW1, which becomes a very low resistance. However, when SW1 is opened, C will charge again very slowly by comparison, because current is limited by the much larger resistance R. This translates to a gate potential able to fall very quickly, but rise only slowly.

In the middle, we have the exact opposite scenario, where C is able to charge to +5V very quickly, but discharges much slower.

On the right charging *and* discharging is very rapid. When SW1 is closed and SW2 open (as shown), the gate capacitance C is able to discharge very quickly  via the low resistance of SW1. I'm sure I don't need to explain the converse situation.

None of this has anything to do with the *type* of output transistor. Both N-channel and P-channel devices will respond exactly as quickly as their gate potentials can change, with some caveats regarding what the output is actually connected to.

Of course it's possible for the load on the output to constrain rate of change of potential there, perhaps causing rate of rise to differ from rate of fall, but assuming no such asymmetry exists at the output, it is asymmetry at the *gate* which chiefly determines rise/fall asymmetry at the output.

Answer (score 0):

Turn-off slew rate depends on load current only as each switch opens.  Turn-On slew rate is fastest due to T=RC when the switch is on at R=RdsOn.

The same is true for collector slew rates in a BJT transitor.  Turn off time depends on the pullup-R * C =T where C can be stray capacitance to ground.

The 1st principal is **$$dV/dt=Ic/C=V/RC$$** For any load capacitance including FET Coss ( which also increases with power rating and RdsOn value).

So an open drain turns off the slowest into a high R load. While reducing Ron may or may not increase slew rate so the product of RdsOn and Coss is often a Figure of Merit (FOM) for power FETs.

Since Nch switches ON low it, therefore, relies on the Pch to turn ON after some dead-time to pull up fast.